# Question regarding cardinally equivalent sets

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I have come across a question regarding cardinally equivalent sets. The question is as follows -

> If $X = \{(x, y) : x^2 + y^2 = z^2\}$, and $Y = \{(x, y) : x^2 + y^2 = a^2\}$ then prove that $X $ and $Y $ are cardinally equivalent sets.

I have been successful and proving it intuitively, but I am unable to write a formal proof for the same.

A detailed formal proof would be helpful.

Comment: They are two circles : one of radius $z$ and another of radius $a$. Define a bijection using polar coordinates.

Comment: In your first set $X = \{(x,y) : x^2 + y^2 = z^2\}$, what is $z$?

Comment: $a$ and $z $ are unknown variables .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think in $\mathbb{R}^2$ this sets are two circles, hence consider the following function $f\colon X\to Y$.

For a point $x\in X$ draw a straight line from the origin passing through $x$, this line will intersect $Y$ in exactly one point, call this point $f(x)$.

If you call $g\colon Y\to X$ another function that does the same as $f$ but the other way around you will find that these two functions are inverses of each other.

Thus, we have bijections between the sets so they have the same cardinality.

Answer (score 1):

{ (a.sin t, a.cos t) : t in [0,2$\pi$) }
is a circle of radius a centered at the origin.
Thus the circle has c = |[0,2 $\pi$)| many points.
From this, it is easy to see every circle has c many points.
Hence all circles are equinumerous.

Comment: Can I please be provided a more detailed proof ?